# Accessing the content of other tabs in a browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, tabs

I am using Mozilla Firefox and I am trying to figure out a way to access the content of other tabs in the same window using JavaScript and the DOM (I am open to other techniques if exist).

**E.g.**, I want to run JavaScript code in `tab1` which can find the title of some other tab. Basically I need this so that I can identify a tab which has opened due an `href` in my current page without using `window.open` method. All I want is a simple hyperlink which opens a page belonging to the same domain as the current page (the page should be opened in a new tab). Now I want to be able to access this new tab from the current tab.

Comment: Maybe look into WebStorage and IndexedDB.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [HTML5 cross-window messaging (archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20110204051705/http://ajaxian.com/archives/cross-window-messaging-with-html-5-postmessage)...but that's kind of cutting edge.

Even in that case, you'd probably need to hijack the <a> tag 'click' event with JavaScript and open the window yourself so that you'd have access to the new window object for posting messages.

Comment: Looks like we made a lot of steps forward in the last six years :)
http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging

Comment: @Loupax As long as you're [not supporting IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226924/is-cross-origin-postmessage-broken-in-ie10).

Answer (score 17):

Whilst you can easily open a new window using JavaScript, I'm sure that is as far as it goes. From a security point of view you wouldn't want JavaScript in one tab being able to query / access the DOM in another tab.  Any site would then be able to gain access to your bank account details, etc. if both sites were opened in separate tabs.

Comment: yes..I know that. But, as I mentioned earlier, the new tab/window will belong to the same domain, so I won't possibly "steal" bank account details from my own website. Anyways thanks for your prompt reply guys...but need to find a workaround for this. - Thanks again

Comment: Can you create a similar effect by tracking open tabs server-side? E.g. suppose you have intentionally coded certain links to open in a new tab, then you know the user has two tabs open. Further, if you have client side js (ajax) "checking in" every few seconds from both tabs, inter-tab communication could be relayed through the server. E.g. perhaps tab 1 is editing "Zoo" object and changes its name from "Boston" to "Denver". Tab 2 is "Boston Zoo Animals" where you can change the animals in the zoo. Tab 2 gets updated to "Denver Zoo Animals" with ajax update.

Answer (score 12):

You can access the new window/tab if it was opened with JavaScript and the page indeed is in the same domain.

You can open the window/tab like so

```
var win = window.open("/path_to_page");
```

Then you'll have to wait for the page to load before you can access e.g. the title.

```
win.onload = function(){ alert(win.document.title); };
```

Comment: Just make sure both pages have the same origin or you will get the following error: `Blocked a frame with origin "http://x" from accessing a frame with origin "http://y". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

Answer (score 10):

Try setting a cookie which is accessible to any page in the same domain. On other pages, use a JavaScript timer to check if the cookie value has changed and when it has you can use its value and take an action.

It worked for me.

Comment: Or you could use localStorage; but cookies has more reach for older browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this would not be possible, you could try

```html
<a target="_blank" rel="opener" href="about:blank"></a>
```

This makes a link that opens an about:blank, this will have the same domain as the page that opened It because of the Same-Origen-policy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).