# Passing data from tab 1 to tab 2

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, tabs

I'm new to stackoverflow and I came here because I couldn't find clear answers to my problems with html and javascript.

I'm wanting to display an HTML page with 3 buttons and the buttons will execute 3 scripts onClick. I need tab#1 to talk to tab#2 to execute the code but I'm stuck on how I go about doing that - here's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!-- START STAGE 1 -->
<script>
function stage1()
{
// Here I want to open up a new tab so I'd do:
window.open('http://webpage.com', '_blank');
}
</script>

<!-- START STAGE 2 -->
<script>
function stage2()
{
// From here, I want to execute some JavaScript to the new tab I've opened
}
</script>

<!-- START STAGE 3 -->
<script>
function stage3()
{
// Again, I want to execute another script on the new tab I've opened
}
</script>

<button type="button" onClick="stage1()">STAGE1</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" onClick="stage2()">STAGE2</button>
<hr />
<button type="button" onClick="stage3()">STAGE3</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd be very appreciated if someone could re-write this code and leave a space in the 3 's for my code to go to be executed on tab#2 from tab#1.

Thank you in advance! - Sorry, I'm a bit of a noob haha.
Cheers,
Declan Land

Comment: You might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203530/accessing-the-content-of-other-tabs-in-browser

Comment: I'll take a look - cheers for the quick reply man!

Comment: what are you showing in each tab?

Comment: 1st tab: my HTML page - 2nd tab: Twitter.

Comment: Why don't you execute the two functions in the second page?

Comment: The second page is from another site - eg: The first tab is mypage.html, when you click on a <button> on mypage.html, it will open twitter.com - now I need mypage.html to open twitter.com and execute a script at startup if possible?

Answer (score 0):

It won't be straightforward, but I think you could do it with a "proxy" page that displays the intended site (Twitter) in an `iframe` and runs the scripts you need when you pass a parameter in the address (e.g., `proxy.htm?action=step2` ) or even use a separate dedicated proxy page (`proxy2.htm`) for each step.

But in order for this to work, I believe you need to use a custom name for the target of your anchor links (`a target="proxy_twitter"`), so all links open in the same tab.

A possible issue would be that the 2nd tab would reload the proxy page on each click, but maybe this can be avoided by changing the parameters to be hashtags (`proxy.htm#action=step2`).

I myself don't have any experience with this mechanism, but I've seen it used on some sites.