# JS - Accessing Multiple Chrome Tabs

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, tabs

How can i access multiple chrome tabs in a single tab ?

For example

I got 10 chrome tabs (windows), running different task
and i want to access the data of those 10 tabs using only 1 single window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the content of other tabs in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203530/accessing-the-content-of-other-tabs-in-browser)

Comment: Also see [**Communication between tabs or windows**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows) and [**Javascript communication between browser tabs/windows**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079280/javascript-communication-between-browser-tabs-windows).